# Installation of R version 3.3.2 Error - caught segmentation fault address 0x0, 'cause' memory not mapped

Tags: macos, r, segmentation-fault

I currently can run the most recent version 3.6.1 of R on my mac however I need to install an older version (specifically version 3.3.2) in order to run analysis in a different application (nSolver).

I installed it by downloading the installer off CRAN and it seemed to work fine. However when I open R I get the following output:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:
1: getDLLRegisteredRoutines.DLLInfo(dll, addNames = FALSE)
2: assignNativeRoutines(dlls[[lib]], lib, env, nsInfo$nativeRoutines[[lib]])
3: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
7: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
8: try({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
9: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly)
10: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
11: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
12: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
13: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly),     error = function(e) e)
14: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
15: .OptRequireMethods()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I've tried uninstalling all versions of R and running the installer again, as well as installing XQuartz, Clang-8.0.0 and gfortran 6.1 again but I get the same error.
I believe someone previously had a similar question and had R version folders in their system library as well as their user library. I do not have this issue (to the best of my knowledge).

I am not very familiar with terminal or how to debug this and would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The R application is specific to the version so even if you have more than one version of R in framework and use Rswitch to change the current version it cannot run. I ended up downloading R 3.3.2 copying the application then downloaded R 3.6.1 which only updated the original application and not the copy. Now with two applications (one for each version) Rswitch seems to work and Rstudio can uses the version set to current.